# A resume can have a title as RESUME?

Tags: writing, style, formal-language

I hear from different sources that a *resume* should not have the title 'RESUME'

Can any one please clarify this formality please?

Comment: This is a very interesting question. +1. I have seen both the examples. With and without the title. Let others come with their answers. Good one!

Comment: It's unnecessary. Anyone looking at it will know it's a resume without the label, and using that as a title causes the person's name to be pushed down from the top spot on the page, forcing the resume reader to hunt a little harder for the name.

Comment: It's not really an English Language Learner question though. It may belong on [The Workplace SE site](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/) but I don't know their rules.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about formalities and conventions in the professional world, not about learning the English language.

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't write BOOK on the cover of a book, and you wouldn't write ARTICLE as the headline for a newspaper article. Similarly, you wouldn't write QUESTION as the title of an ELL question. For this reason, it's considered inappropriate to write RESUME as the title of a resumé.

Most resumé guides say to just use your name as the title. I can see why that would be awkward, too, since most of us aren't used to naming documents after ourselves. After all, it would be strange for me to ask a question on ELL, and entitle the question **J.R.** However, that's the convention that has been established in business, and just another example of why context is so important.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use the word resume at all, let alone without the accent, which makes it sound like you're about to recommence something you put on hold earlier.

I'd use Curriculum Vitae, or even just CV, & include it as a sub-header.

> ## My Name
>
> #### Curriculum Vitae
>
> rest of text

Curriculum Vitae/Resumé preference might be a US/rest of the world difference, according to [The Difference Between a Curriculum Vitae (CV) and a Resume](http://jobsearch.about.com/cs/curriculumvitae/f/cvresume.htm)